# Get al office 365 outlook's contact folders

Tags: outlook, office365, office-js, office365api

I am looking to get All Contact folders in Outlook using https://oauthplay.azurewebsites.net/. However, for some reason I cannot get the default "Contacts" folder, just the ones created by the user. For example, I did a GET on https://outlook.office.com/api/v2.0/me/contactfolders, and this is an example of the result:

```
{
    "value": [
        {
            "Id": "AAMkAGU0ZjM2ZWQ2LTZiYjQtNDY2Ny1hMTBjLTZmOTM4ZTMyMmRlNQAuAAAAAADfJok2QyPPRKN0MNMI2ntdAQAjvTBpWNeCQYCyqAy3mDiPAAAAAAFbAAA=",
            "ParentFolderId": "AAMkAGU0ZjM2ZWQ2LTZiYjQtNDY2Ny1hMTBjLTZmOTM4ZTMyMmRlNQAuAAAAAADfJok2QyPPRKN0MNMI2ntdAQAjvTBpWNeCQYCyqAy3mDiPAAAAAAEOAAA=",
            "DisplayName": "Test1"
        },
        {
            "Id": "AI2ntdAQAjvTBpWNeCQYCyqAy3mDiPAAAAAAFcAAA=",
            "ParentFolderId": "0MNMI2ntdAQAjvTBpWNeCQYCyqAy3mDiPAAAAAAEOAAA=",
            "DisplayName": "Test2"
        }
    ]
}
```

Any idea how to get the default contact folder?

Answer (score 0):

You could use this api:

https://outlook.office.com/api/v2.0/me/contactfolders

This will get the contact folder collection under the default Contacts folder of the signed-in user (.../me/contactfolders), or under the specified contact folder.

For more information, please refer to this link:

[Outlook Contacts REST API reference (version 2.0)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/office-365-api/api/version-2.0/contacts-rest-operations)

Comment: Hello, as per original description the above api call will not get the actual Contact folder, just the ones created by user